# Redirect is slow in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want redirect page when user click on the send button and data is submitted. I do that with Laravel but in my codes redirect is doing very slow and it takes a few seconds while I want to be done immediately.

My codes:

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'ArticleController@index')->name('article.index');
Route::get('article/create', 'ArticleController@createView');
Route::post('article/create', 'ArticleController@create')->name('article.create');
```

ArticleController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::latest()->take(10)->get();
        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    public function createView()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    public function create(ArticleRequest $request)
    {

        Article::create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'body' => $request->input('body')
        ]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

My form HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('article.create') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control text-justify space-normal" name="body" id="body" placeholder="Text..." rows="15"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**Update:**
My problem is indicated in the screenshots below. Which acts differently in php and laravel languages.

in laravel:

[image]

[image]

in php:

[image]

please help.
thanks all.

Comment: Most likely your database is very slow. Try doing the redirect without creating the Article.

Comment: You can shutdown your system and restart. may be there some processes that are running which consumes your resources

Comment: post your `ArticleRequest` validation

Comment: please review my update i add new description and images of my problem

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is slow?

Might be an issue with your coding or query with the database

You are trying to redirect on `article.index` route check `ArticleController@index` on your query and query execution time. install this: [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Always try to use standard way for redirect

you can use something like that

```
return redirect(route('article.index')); //after update data
```

My suggestion is to use laravel debugbar and you can improve your codes and queries

Comment: please review my update i add new description and images of my problem